# My OpenShift cluster the Storage class automatically creates a new one after I deleted them. How can I delete them?

Tags: openshift

I have plan to replace storage class to another datastore in the same name, But when deleted them it's automatically creates a new one after I deleted them, How can I delete them?

I have plan to replace storage class to another datastore in the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenShift Cluster Storage Operator [creates default storage classes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/post_installation_configuration/storage-configuration.html#defining-storage-classes_post-install-storage-configuration) that cannot be changed:

> The Cluster Storage Operator might install a default storage class depending on the platform in use. This storage class is owned and controlled by the Operator. It cannot be deleted or modified beyond defining annotations and labels. If different behavior is desired, you must define a custom storage class.

So in your case you likely want to create a new storage class with your custom datastore and then [set the new storage class as default](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/post_installation_configuration/storage-configuration.html#change-default-storage-class_post-install-storage-configuration).